# DSC, compiling a ps1 file into MOF

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to configure a target node via DSC.
I've created a .ps1 file with a dummy Configuration; you can see it below; it's just one of the first examples that you find in DSC sites.
Now I want to compile it into .mof file.
I've executed:

```
PS C:\var\DSC\Configurations> . .\localhost.ps1
```

but it does nothing. The mof file doesn't appear and no error messages are thrown. 
What am I missing?

```
Configuration FileResourceDemo
{
Node "localhost"
{
    File DirectoryCopy
    {
        Ensure = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
        Type = "Directory" # Default is "File".
        Recurse = $true # Ensure presence of subdirectories, too
        SourcePath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DSCDemo\DemoSource"
        DestinationPath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DSCDemo\DemoDestination"    
    }

    Log AfterDirectoryCopy
    {
        # The message below gets written to the Microsoft-Windows-Desired  State Configuration/Analytic log
        Message = "Finished running the file resource with ID DirectoryCopy"
        DependsOn = "[File]DirectoryCopy" # This means run "DirectoryCopy"  first.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Configuration` keyword only *defines* the configuration (think of it like the `function` keyword). After that you have to execute it, by calling it like a function (it can even have parameters, though yours does not).

So if, at the end of your `.ps1` file you add:

```
FileResourceDemo
```

It will execute it right after defining it.

Or, since you are dot sourcing the file according to your question, you can directly execute it interactively by typing `FileResourceDemo` into the prompt. It should even tab-complete.